# Testing Hash Table

Tags: linked-list, hashtable

I need to test if my hash table works right, but it fails the test as my hash table doesn't seem to find any elements. No problems in compiler, neither through debugger, it's somewhere in the logic of the code. I thought it's because of insert() function, but it seems ok to me, as I tried changing it times again, but nothing helped. Can you look through the code and tell me what can be wrong with it please?

Here's what console shows me:

My HashTable:
Time: 0.610612, after insert: 270717, after erase:270717, found: 0
STL unordered_map:
Time: 0.67032, after insert: 316124, after erase: 115991, found: 115884

:(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_map>
 
using namespace std;
const int M = 10000;
const double MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75;
 
long long generateRandLong() {
    int numDigits = rand() % 19 + 10; // Random number of digits between 10 and 19
    unsigned long long num = rand() % 9 + 1; // Random non-zero first digit
    for (int i = 1; i < numDigits; i++) {
        unsigned long long digit = rand() % 10;
        num = num * 10 + digit;
    }
    return num % (unsigned long long)(pow(10, 18));
}
 
 
string generateRandColor() {
    string colors[] = { "black", "white", "gold", "rose gold", "silver" };
    return colors[rand() % 5];
}
 
struct Data {
    long long key;
    long long number;
    string color;
    bool is_charger;
 
    Data() {
        key = generateRandLong();
        number = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        color = generateRandColor();
        is_charger = rand() % 2;
    }
};
 
struct HashNode {
    long long key;
    Data data;
    HashNode* next;
    HashNode* prev; //doubly
 
    // constructor
    HashNode(Data data) {
        this->key = data.key;
        this->data = data;
        next = nullptr;
        prev = nullptr;
}
 
    HashNode(long long k, Data v) : key(k), data(v), next(nullptr) {}
};
 
struct LinkedList {
    HashNode* head = nullptr;
    HashNode* tail = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
    
    ~LinkedList() {
        clear();
    }
 
    void push_front(HashNode* newHashNode) { 
    //head->prev = newNode; //doubly
    head = newHashNode; 
    if (tail == nullptr) { 
        tail = newHashNode; 
    }
    size++;
}
 
    HashNode* getHead() {
        return head;
    }
    
    void clear() {
        HashNode* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            HashNode* next = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
    
bool remove(long long key) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    if (head->data.key == key) {
        HashNode* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    HashNode* current = head;
    while (current->next != nullptr && current->next->data.key != key) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current->next == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    HashNode* temp = current->next;
    current->next = temp->next;
    if (temp == tail) {
        tail = current;
    }
    delete temp;
    size--;
    return true;
}
    
    bool search(long long key) {
        HashNode* current = head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            if (current->data.key == key) {
                return true;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
 
 
struct HashTable {
 
    LinkedList* bucketsArray;
    int bucketCount;
    bool isEmpty = true;
    int uniqueKeyCount = 0;
    float MAX_LOAD_FACTOR;
 
    // Hash function for long long keys
    int hash(long long key) {
        return key % bucketCount;
    }
 
    HashTable(int initialBucketCount, float MAX_LOAD_FACTOR) {
        bucketCount = initialBucketCount;
        this->MAX_LOAD_FACTOR = MAX_LOAD_FACTOR;
        bucketsArray = new LinkedList[bucketCount];
    }
 
    ~HashTable() {
        delete[] bucketsArray;
    }
 
void rehash() {
    int oldBucketCount = bucketCount;
    bucketCount *= 2;
    LinkedList* newBucketsArray = new LinkedList[bucketCount];
    uniqueKeyCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldBucketCount; i++) {
        HashNode* current = bucketsArray[i].getHead();
        while (current != nullptr) {
            HashNode* newNode = new HashNode(current->data);
            int bucketIndex = hash(current->data.key);
            newBucketsArray[bucketIndex].push_front(newNode);
            uniqueKeyCount++;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    delete[] bucketsArray;
    bucketsArray = newBucketsArray;
}
 
 
void insert(long long key, Data value) {
    int bucketIndex = hash(key);
    HashNode* current = bucketsArray[bucketIndex].getHead();
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->data.key == key) {
            current->data = value;
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    HashNode* newHashNode = new HashNode(key, value);
    bucketsArray[bucketIndex].push_front(newHashNode);
    uniqueKeyCount++;
 
    double loadFactor = (double)uniqueKeyCount / bucketCount;
    if (loadFactor > MAX_LOAD_FACTOR) {
        rehash();
    }
}
 
    
bool erase(long long key) {
    int bucketIndex = hash(key);
    bool found = bucketsArray[bucketIndex].remove(key);
    if (found) {
        uniqueKeyCount--;
        float loadFactor = (float)uniqueKeyCount / bucketCount;
        if (loadFactor < MAX_LOAD_FACTOR / 2) {
            rehash();
        }
    }
    return found;
}
 
    bool find(long long key) {
        int bucketIndex = hash(key);
        return bucketsArray[bucketIndex].search(key);
    }
 
    int size() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++) {
            LinkedList& bucket = bucketsArray[i];
            HashNode* current = bucket.getHead();
            while (current != nullptr) {
                count++;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
 
};
```

I think the origin problem is in insert() coz it's the first one which crashes. Also, here's the test code, but it should be right, as it was given to me for the testing specifically.

```
bool testHashTable()
{
    const int iters = 500000;
    const int keysAmount = iters * 1;
 
    // generate random keys:
    long long* keys = new long long[keysAmount];
 
    long long* keysToInsert = new long long[iters];
    long long* keysToErase = new long long[iters];
    long long* keysToFind = new long long[iters];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < keysAmount; i++)
    {
        keys[i] = generateRandLong();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        keysToInsert[i] = keys[generateRandLong() % keysAmount];
        keysToErase[i] = keys[generateRandLong() % keysAmount];
        keysToFind[i] = keys[generateRandLong() % keysAmount];
    }
 
    // test my HashTable:
    HashTable hashTable(500000, 0.75);
 
    clock_t myStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        hashTable.insert(keysToInsert[i], Data());
    }
    int myInsertSize = hashTable.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        hashTable.erase(keysToErase[i]);
    }
    int myEraseSize = hashTable.size();
    int myFoundAmount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        if (hashTable.find(keysToFind[i]))
        {   
            myFoundAmount++;
        }
    }
    clock_t myEnd = clock();
    float myTime = (float(myEnd - myStart)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 
    // test STL hash table:
    unordered_map<long long, Data> unorderedMap;
 
    clock_t stlStart = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        unorderedMap.insert({keysToInsert[i], Data()});
    }
    int stlInsertSize = unorderedMap.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        unorderedMap.erase(keysToErase[i]);
    }
    int stlEraseSize = unorderedMap.size();
    int stlFoundAmount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
    {
        if (unorderedMap.find(keysToFind[i]) != unorderedMap.end())
        {
            stlFoundAmount++;
        }
    }
    clock_t stlEnd = clock();
    float stlTime = (float(stlEnd - stlStart)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 
    cout << "My HashTable:" << endl;
    cout << "Time: " << myTime << ", after insert: " << myInsertSize << ", after erase: " << myEraseSize << ", found: " << myFoundAmount << endl;
    cout << "STL unordered_map:" << endl;
    cout << "Time: " << stlTime << ", after insert: " << stlInsertSize << ", after erase: " << stlEraseSize << ", found: " << stlFoundAmount << endl << endl;
 
    delete[] keys;
    delete[] keysToInsert;
    delete[] keysToErase;
    delete[] keysToFind;
 
    if (myInsertSize == stlInsertSize && myEraseSize == stlEraseSize && myFoundAmount == stlFoundAmount)
    {
        cout << "The lab is completed" << endl;
        return true;
    }
 
    cerr << ":(" << endl;
    return false;
}
 
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    testHashTable();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what you do: You write a function that checks whether the dat structures in your hash table are consistent, and prints the complete contents of the hash table. You call that after every operation that changes the hash table. And then you run your tests.

Either you find the operation that messed up your table, or you go from correct table -> operation -> crash. In that case use the debugger and set a breakpoint on the crashing function.